# I have found most of everything I need and have a "mostly" working game

Tags: python-2.7

I having issues with the def check guess. It's the format my teacher specifically gave. You guys are great. Thanks for the help!!!! Sorry for the format this is my first time on this site.

```
# # Global variables    
wrong_guesses = []
target_phrase = ""
current_phrase = ""

def clear_display():
    for i in range(20):
        print "\n"

def string_with_dashes(str):    
    global target_phrase
    new_phrase = ""
    for i in str:
        if i.isalpha():
            new_phrase += "-"
        else:
            new_phrase += i
    return new_phrase

def check_guess(letter):    
    global current_phrase
    replacement_list = [""]
    for i in range(len(target_phrase)):
        if target_phrase[i] == letter:
            replacement_list[i] = target_phrase[i]
            current_phrase = replacement_list
            return current_phrase
        else:
            wrong_guesses.append(letter)
            return False

def process_input():  
    user_letter = raw_input("Guess a letter: ").upper()
    if user_letter in wrong_guesses:
        print "You already guessed that letter"
        user_letter = raw_input("Guess again : ")
    else:
         return check_guess(user_letter)

def one_turn():    
    global wrong_guesses     
    print "=================================================="
    print current_phrase
    print "Wrong guesses:", ' '.join(wrong_guesses)
    print "Guesses remaining:", (8 - len(wrong_guesses))
    display_robot(8 - len(wrong_guesses))
    print "String to guess:", current_phrase
    print "=================================================="
    process_input()
    print "\n\n"

def setup_phrase():    
    global target_phrase, current_phrase
    target_phrase = raw_input("Dear friend, enter a phrase for the user to guess: ").upper()
    current_phrase = string_with_dashes(target_phrase)

setup_phrase()
clear_display()

while True:
    one_turn()
    if len(wrong_guesses) > 7:
        print "GAME OVER! You Lose"
        breack
    if current_phrase == target_phrase:
        print "You WIN!!"
        break
```

(why won't stackoverflow let me fix your code?)

Comment: How do I tell it where exactly to replace the letter(s), with len()?

Comment: `i in target_phrase` only returns `True` or `False` to tell you whether or not `target_phrase` contains `i`. You need to use something else such as `find()` or iterating over the string to find out where to replace the letter(s).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but it sounds like you want to create a string where the guessed letters replace blanks as they are guessed? Try something like this:

```
hidden_phrase = "abracadabra"
current_list = ["."]*len(hidden_phrase)

def check_guess(letter):
    for i in range(len(hidden_phrase)):
        if hidden_phrase[i] == letter:
            current_list [i] = hidden_phrase[i]

print("before", "".join(current_list ))
check_guess("a")
print("guess1", "".join(current_list))
check_guess("z")
print("guess2", "".join(current_list))
check_guess("b")
print("guess3", "".join(current_list))
```

Output:

```
before ...........
guess1 a..a.a.a..a
guess2 a..a.a.a..a
guess3 ab.a.a.ab.a
```

In Python strings are immutable, and can't be updated, so it seems easier to me to keep the 'replacement' word (with blanks, which I represent with `.`) as a list, and join it back together for display.

The two global variables don't need to be explicitly specified as `global`, because the variable is not assigned to in the function, only accessed.

If you prefer to have a string `current_phrase` and update that, of course that's possible too:

```
hidden_phrase = "abracadabra"
current_phrase = "."*len(hidden_phrase )

def check_guess(letter):
    global current_phrase
    i = -1
    while True:
        i = hidden_phrase.find(letter, i+1)
        if i<0:
            break
        current_phrase = current_phrase[0:i]+letter + current_phrase[i+1:]

print("before", current_phrase)
check_guess("a")
print("guess1", current_phrase)
check_guess("z")
print("guess2", current_phrase)
check_guess("b")
print("guess3", current_phrase)
```

This time you need the `global` again to prevent `current_phrase = ...` from creating a local variable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I still having trouble. Here is the whole code I have. The teachers gave us these specific def  functions to use.    How do I post the code in the correct format? It just places it on there in paragraph?? Sorry, thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't post blocks of code in a comment. Edit the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was to the first, more general, version of your question. Several things were wrong with your `check_guess()`. Here's a fixed version:

```
def check_guess(letter):    
    global current_phrase
    replacement_list = list(current_phrase)
    found=False
    for i in range(len(target_phrase)):
        if target_phrase[i] == letter:
            replacement_list[i] = target_phrase[i]
            found = True
    if found:
        current_phrase = "".join(replacement_list)
    else:
        wrong_guesses.append(letter)
```

Comments to show problems with your version:

```
def check_guess(letter):    
    global current_phrase
    replacement_list = [""] # list has only 1 element, can't assign above index zero
    for i in range(len(target_phrase)):
        if target_phrase[i] == letter:
            replacement_list[i] = target_phrase[i]
            current_phrase = replacement_list # assigning a list to what was previously a string
            return current_phrase # returns before checking 2nd character
        else:
            wrong_guesses.append(letter) # only the first character has been checked
            return False # returns False or current_phrase, inconsistent
```

Also near the end you wrote `breack` instead of `break`, it's a shame that Python doesn't check these things by default, waiting instead for you to hit that line.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH!!!! I've been working on this for 2 days and was going nuts!! As a mechanic I never thought coding would be so hard to learn. You made my day Galax, thank you for all your help and patience!!!

Comment: No problem, yes it's hard at the beginning- you have to understand exactly what each line of code is doing, you will get there with practice though.